# Is there a design pattern for one input passed to n methods that each return the input for the next method

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, method-chaining

**I'd like to know if there is a design pattern for this problem:**

One input is used to construct an object (via constructor or via method return I don't care), that object is feed to the next method or constructor. This is repeated on a user specified set of processors, obviously throwing exceptions if there is a break in the chain of required inputs for the processors.

The output of all, some or none of the implemented processors is the same object.

I've got about 6 processors planned, possibly more in future.

**Composition:**
I'm not sure I like the composition design pattern because not every object is intended to be an output of this process and I can't think how to not output null values without the user knowing it's going to be null.

**Chain of responsibility:**
Chain of responsibility is the way to go according to what I've heard however I'm not sure i understand it. Is this design pattern suggesting to pass n function pointers to a function that runs through each? If so, I'm not sure how to setup the function that gets passed n function pointers.

**my attempt:**

I've got two interface that are inherited by n classes ie (FirstProcessor, FirstInput, FirstOutput, SecondProcessor, SecondOutput, ThirdProcessor,.., NProcessor, NOutput)

```
    IChainedOutput
    {
        IChainedOutput Input {get;} 
        FinalOutputOBj GetFinalOutput()
    }

    IChainedProcessor
    {
        IChainedOutput Run(IChainedOutput previousOutput)
    }
```

used like this:

```
    IChainedProcessor previous = FirstProcessor(originalInput)

    foreach(IChainedProcessor processor in processorList.Skip(1)
    {
        IChainedOutput current = processor.Run(previous)

        previous = current;       
    }

    FinalOutputObj output = previous.GetFinalOutput();
```

**Problems:**

1. FinalOutputObj is coupled with all the processor implementations which is bad. It's not comprised of all the IChainedOutput child class members but uses a good subset to calculate other values.
2. FinalOutputObj is being composed in a bad way and I don't see how I can escape from outputting null values if the list of processors does not contain every processor implemented.
3. There is a lot of downcasting in the constructors of the child classes which is a red flag for oop. However, the inputs for each block of processing logic are completely different. First input is a couple of vectors, second input is the output of the first which includes a handful of custom types and more vectors, etc
4. Each IChainedOutput contains the reference to the inputs used to create it. currently there is one to one mapping input to processor but i'm not sure in future. And this is more bad downcasting.
5. I'd like to not have to perfectly organise the list of processors, makes it too easy for other developers to make mistakes here. so the next one selected should be the one that has the correct constructor.

Comment: Sounds like a DataFlow pipeline

Comment: What is the purpose of putting these processors in a list? Normally if you need to run several methods you just code each step one after the other, e.g. as separate lines within a .cs file, not as items in a list.

Comment: Sounds like Chain of Responsibility though I guess you could use a Observers too depending on the flow.

Comment: @JohnWu if you look at my description you'll see that i mention that the list is user specified. If the user wants a rougher quick solution they could select the first few processors. There are at least two processors that provide fancy output that not every use case will want or need.

Comment: As already mentioned by @TheGeneral - have you had a go at [DataFlow pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline)?

Comment: To me it sounds like 
[fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C#) more than anything...

Comment: Can the order of the processors be completely random? Or is the case that if you have processors 123456 that you can only omit processors so that it becomes 12-4-6 meaning the general order remains the same? In other words having a chain 6-25-4 is not possible?

Comment: @Reasurria No they can't be completely random. 6-25-4 would be impossible. The output needs to be the same as a processors input. Currently it's one to one (one processor output matches one processor input) but if the solution is simple, then in some of my cases it would make sense to have the output of one processor be the input for multiple other processors.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a decorator approach like this:

```
public interface IChainProcessor
{
    IChainOutput Run(IChainOutput previousOutput);
}

public interface IChainOutput
{
    string Value { get; }
}

public class OutputExample : IChainOutput
{
    public string Value { get; }

    public OutputExample(string value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

public abstract class Processor : IChainProcessor
{
    protected IChainProcessor nextProcessor;

    public IChainOutput Run(IChainOutput previousOutput)
    {
        var myOutput = this.MyLogic(previousOutput);

        return this.nextProcessor == null ? myOutput : this.nextProcessor.Run(myOutput);
    }

    protected abstract IChainOutput MyLogic(IChainOutput input);
}

public class ProcessorA : Processor
{
    public ProcessorA() { }

    public ProcessorA(ProcessorB nextProcessor)
    {
        this.nextProcessor = nextProcessor;
    }

    protected override IChainOutput MyLogic(IChainOutput input)
    {
        return new OutputExample($"{input.Value} + Processor_A_Output"); 
    }
}

public class ProcessorB : ProcessorA
{
    public ProcessorB() { }

    public ProcessorB(ProcessorC nextProcessor)
    {
        this.nextProcessor = nextProcessor;
    }

    protected override IChainOutput MyLogic(IChainOutput input)
    {
        return new OutputExample($"{input.Value} + Processor_B_Output");  
    }
}

public class ProcessorC : ProcessorB
{
    protected override IChainOutput MyLogic(IChainOutput input)
    {
        return new OutputExample($"{input.Value} + Processor_C_Output"); 
    }
}
```

The usage would be something like the below:

```
private static int Main(string[] args)
{
    var chain = new ProcessorA(new ProcessorB(new ProcessorC()));
    var simpleChain = new ProcessorA(new ProcessorC());
    var verySimpleChain = new ProcessorA();

    var initialInput = new OutputExample("Start");

    Console.WriteLine(chain.Run(initialInput).Value);
    Console.WriteLine(simpleChain.Run(initialInput).Value);
    Console.WriteLine(verySimpleChain.Run(initialInput).Value);

    return 0;
 }
```

The output of this example is:

```
Start + Processor_A_Output + Processor_B_Output + Processor_C_Output
Start + Processor_A_Output + Processor_C_Output
Start + Processor_A_Output
```

The abstract Processor class provides a template method that you can implement in subclasses. So every ProcessorX class only defines `MyLogic(IChainOutput input)`

The Processors extend each other to enforce compile time preservation of processor order. So it is impossible to build a chain where ProcessorB comes before ProcessorA. It is possible though to build a chain that omits some processors as in the above example.

The example I provide here does not cater for the final output, which I know is one of your main concerns. To deal with issue I would rather build a mapping class to convert IChainOutput into the final format (I don't know the real structure of your data so maybe this is not possible).

> in some of my cases it would make sense to have the output of one processor be the input for multiple other processors

Using this pattern it would also be possible to construct a processor 'tree' rather than a chain, by allowing the Processor class to have a list of next steps. Your usage would then become something like this:

```
var chain = new ProcessorA(new ProcessorB(new ProcessorC()), new ProcessorB(new ProcessorD()));
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your explanation correctly you can use delegates to overcome your problem. One of the important point about delegates is that they can be chained together so that you can call any number of methods in a single event.

Comment: This is not very useful. Yes, you can chain them but how are you suggesting to deal with the changing inputs and variable outputs.

Answer (score -1):

Each processor transforming specific input into a specific output. Therefore the processor implementation should know only two types.

```
public interface IStepProcessor<TInput, TOutput>
{
    TOutput Process(TInput input);
}
```

The client code ideally should know only two type of data that is input data and final product. The client code don't care if there were some intermediary steps in the middle. Client make use the conveyor as a black box

```
public delegate TOutput Conveyor<TInput, TOutput>(TInput input);
```

Yet some external code should understand how the whole transformation is done. This code should know all the intermediate data types and have access to all intermediate processors. It is done best with dependency injection.

```
public class Factory
{
    private readonly IStepProcessor<IDataInput, IDataStep1> m_Step1;
    private readonly IStepProcessor<IDataStep1, IDataStep2> m_Task2;
    private readonly IStepProcessor<IDataStep2, IDataStep3> m_Task3;
    private readonly IStepProcessor<IDataStep3, IDataStepN> m_TaskN;
    private readonly IStepProcessor<IDataStepN, IDataOutput> m_FinalTask;

    public Factory(
        IStepProcessor<IDataInput, IDataStep1> task1,
        IStepProcessor<IDataStep1, IDataStep2> task2,
        IStepProcessor<IDataStep2, IDataStep3> task3,
        IStepProcessor<IDataStep3, IDataStepN> taskN,
        IStepProcessor<IDataStepN, IDataOutput> finalTask
        )
    {
        m_Step1 = task1;
        m_Task2 = task2;
        m_Task3 = task3;
        m_TaskN = taskN;
        m_FinalTask = finalTask;
    }
    public Conveyor<IDataInput, IDataOutput> BuildConveyor()
    {
        return (input) =>
        {
            return m_FinalTask.Process(
                m_TaskN.Process(
                    m_Task3.Process(
                        m_Task2.Process(
                            m_Step1.Process(input)))));
        };
    }
}
```

Here goes my offer

```
public interface IDataInput { }
public interface IDataStep1 { }
public interface IDataStep2 { }
public interface IDataStep3 { }
public interface IDataStepN { }
public interface IDataOutput { }

public interface IStepProcessor<TInput, TOutput>
{
    TOutput Process(TInput input);
}

public delegate TOutput Conveyor<TInput, TOutput>(TInput input);

public class Factory
{
    private readonly IStepProcessor<IDataInput, IDataStep1> m_Step1;
    private readonly IStepProcessor<IDataStep1, IDataStep2> m_Task2;
    private readonly IStepProcessor<IDataStep2, IDataStep3> m_Task3;
    private readonly IStepProcessor<IDataStep3, IDataStepN> m_TaskN;
    private readonly IStepProcessor<IDataStepN, IDataOutput> m_FinalTask;

    public Factory(
        IStepProcessor<IDataInput, IDataStep1> task1,
        IStepProcessor<IDataStep1, IDataStep2> task2,
        IStepProcessor<IDataStep2, IDataStep3> task3,
        IStepProcessor<IDataStep3, IDataStepN> taskN,
        IStepProcessor<IDataStepN, IDataOutput> finalTask
        )
    {
        m_Step1 = task1;
        m_Task2 = task2;
        m_Task3 = task3;
        m_TaskN = taskN;
        m_FinalTask = finalTask;
    }
    public Conveyor<IDataInput, IDataOutput> BuildConveyor()
    {
        return (input) =>
        {
            return m_FinalTask.Process(
                m_TaskN.Process(
                    m_Task3.Process(
                        m_Task2.Process(
                            m_Step1.Process(input)))));
        };
    }
}


public class Client
{
    private readonly Conveyor<IDataInput, IDataOutput> m_Conveyor;

    public Client(Conveyor<IDataInput, IDataOutput> conveyor)
    {
        m_Conveyor = conveyor;
    }

    public void DealWithInputAfterTransformingIt(IDataInput input)
    {
        var output = m_Conveyor(input);
        Console.Write($"Mind your business here {typeof(IDataOutput).IsAssignableFrom(output.GetType())}");
    }
}

public class Program {

    public void StartingPoint(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ISomeDIContainer container = CreateDI();
        container.Register<IStepProcessor<IDataInput, IDataStep1>, Step1Imp>();
        container.Register<IStepProcessor<IDataStep1, IDataStep2>, Step2Imp>();
        container.Register<IStepProcessor<IDataStep2, IDataStep3>, Step3Imp>();
        container.Register<IStepProcessor<IDataStep3, IDataStepN>, StepNImp>();
        container.Register<IStepProcessor<IDataStepN, IDataOutput>, StepOImp>();

        container.Register<Factory>();

        Factory factory = container.Resolve<Factory>();
        var conveyor = factory.BuildConveyor();
        var client = new Client(conveyor);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of repetition here and it does not address the fact that there are a variable number of tasks to do. I'd need to create many more steps and allow uninitialised steps. I'd also need a different instantiation for each task combination. Very verbose. Perhaps I can't escape verbosity.